# Get the Values of the Retrieved Nodes and Use them Globally! (Firebase and Swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get some values from the UserProfile node from the dashboard and pass them into global variables to use them globally outside the observe function.

```
ref.child("UserProfile").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).observeEventType(.Value , withBlock: {snapshot in
        if let name =  snapshot.value!.objectForKey("name") as? String {
        print(name)
        }
        if let email =  snapshot.value!.objectForKey("email") as? String {
        print(email)
        }
        if let phone =  snapshot.value!.objectForKey("phone") as? String {
        print(phone)
        }
        if let city =  snapshot.value!.objectForKey("city") as? String {
        print(city)
        }
    })
```

I want to pass them outside the observe function so I can use them globally anywhere in the .swift file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Firebase functions are supposed to be **Asynchronous**, you need to access these User properties inside the completionBlock of the function. And mind that They will only give retrieved value once the call has been completed.

```
var globalUserName : String!
var globalEmail : String!
var globalPhone : String!
var globalCity : String!

 override func viewWillAppear(animated : Bool){
     super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        retrieveUserData{(name,email,phone,city) in
            self.globalUserName = name
            self.globalEmail = email
            self.globalPhone = phone
            self.globalCity = city
            }

        }

 func retrieveUserData(completionBlock : ((name : String!,email : String!, phone : String!, city : String!)->Void)){
   ref.child("UserProfile").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).observeEventType(.Value , withBlock: {snapshot in

     if let userDict =  snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]  {

          completionBlock(name : userDict["name"] as! String,email : userDict["email"] as! String, phone : userDict["phone"] as! String, city : userDict["city"] as! String)
    }
 })

}
```