# Getting the values of data stored in firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ios-lifecycle

I'm trying to get access to the values stored in firebase dashboard to use them in different functions and methods in the class.

[I used this method in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39497157/get-the-values-of-the-retrieved-nodes-and-use-them-globally-firebase-and-swift)

I have tried to print their values, the whole app has crashed and it gave me that their nil!

They are not nil actually! 
I used a similar method in viewDidLoad and I could retrieve the values to labels!

```
let refer = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("UserDevices")

var globalEmail : String!
var globalPhone : String!
var globalImageUrl: String!


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated : Bool){
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    retrieveUserData{(email,phone,ImageUrl) in
        self.globalEmail = email
        self.globalPhone = phone
        self.globalImageUrl = ImageUrl
    }

}

func retrieveUserData(_ completionBlock : @escaping ((_ email : String?, _ phone : String?, _ ImageUrl: String?)->Void)){
    refer.child(byAppendingPath: self.strUserid as String).observe(.value , with: {snapshot in
        if let userDict =  snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]  {
            completionBlock(userDict["email"] as! String, userDict["phone"] as! String, userDict["ImageUrl"] as! String)
        }
    })
}

var strUserid : NSString!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(globalEmail)
    print(globalImageUrl)
    print(globalPhone)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white

    print("idis \(self.strUserid)")

     let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("UserDevices")

     self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    ref.child(byAppendingPath: self.strUserid as String).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSMutableDictionary{

            print("dict is \(dict)")

            if let Provider = dict["name"] as? String
            {
                self.DeviceDetailsProvider.text = Provider
               // self.navigationItem.title = Provider
            }
            if let name = dict["DeviceName"] as? String
            {
                self.DeviceDetailsName.text = name
                self.navigationItem.title = name
            }
            if let ShortDescription = dict["Description"] as? String
            {
                self.DeviceDetailsDescription.text = ShortDescription
            }
            if let City = dict["city"] as? String
            {
                self.DeviceDetailsCity.text = City
            }

        }
    })


   self.DeviceDetailsImageView.downloadedFrom(link: globalImageUrl)

}
```

Why I'm getting a crash here!

Comment: Which line it is crashing? Mention that where it works and where it crashes!

Comment: No specific line. But the whole app crash

Comment: What do you mean whole app crash?

Answer (score 0):

Change `ref.child(byAppendingPath: self.strUserid as String)`

To:-

```
ref.child(self.strUserid)
```

Also remove `let refer = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("UserDevices")`.

You can not initialise your reference globally outside a scope because you don't know in which order your classes are being initialised, and probable scenario is that your *FIRDatabase* hasn't even been initialised yet when you try to initialise **`let refer`**.

Instead of **`refer`** in *`retrieveUserData`* use

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("UserDevices")
```

You see in a **viewController**'s *LIFE CYCLE*, **viewdidLoad** is called before than **viewWillAppear:**

So what you need is:-

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
  ..
   retrieveUserData{(email,phone,ImageUrl) in
    self.globalEmail = email
    self.globalPhone = phone
    self.globalImageUrl = ImageUrl
     self.DeviceDetailsImageView.downloadedFrom(link: globalImageUrl)
    // .. Do your stuff...

       }

  }
```

[image]

Read: [Viewcontroller's Lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5570363/6297658)

Comment: I'm still having trouble retrieving the values!

Comment: Are you aound here?

Comment: Try printing your global variables before `self.DeviceDetailsImageView.downloadedFrom(link: globalImageUrl)` and check if you are getting the values. If not then check your reference path and to your DB.