# TableView and Button (Crash)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm having a table view that contains this prepareForSegue function:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let upcoming: CategoryDeviceViewController = segue.destination as! CategoryDeviceViewController
    let myindexpath = self.MainPageTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    let titleString = self.CategoryTitle.object(at: ((myindexpath as NSIndexPath?)?.row)!) as? String
    upcoming.titlestring = titleString
    self.MainPageTableView.deselectRow(at: myindexpath!, animated: true)
}
```

To get the title from 6 cells and save them to next view in nvigational bar title.

In this view that contains the prepare for segue function there's a button in navigational bar that moves to another (third) view controller!

Whenever I click on that button the app crashes on this line:

```
let upcoming: CategoryDeviceViewController = segue.destination as! CategoryDeviceViewController
```

I know the reason of the error but how can I solve it?

Comment: What is the reason of the error which you know? And what the logs says about your crash?

Comment: The upcoming should be CategoryDeviceViewController but when clicking on the button it opened the third view controller

Comment: Did you set `destination` viewController properly in your storyboard for this `segue`?

Comment: Use `if (segue.identifier == "upcoming1")` and load accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123885/discussion-between-santosh-and-mariah).

Comment: Use `if (segue.identifier == "upcoming1")` and load accordingly. And in don't forget to set `upcoming1` in storyboard as `segue identifier`

Comment: Can you explain it more in the answer? First did you get exactly what I mean?

Comment: Almost definitely segue.destination is not a CategoryDeviceViewController so the force cast is failing.  Set a breakpoint and see what type of object segue.destination is.

Comment: @ David Shaw Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your segues and crash logs, here is you are missing i guess. Try to identify the destination with your segue identifiers:

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowCategoryDevice" {
        let upcoming: CategoryDeviceViewController = segue.destination as! CategoryDeviceViewController
        let myindexpath = self.MainPageTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let titleString = self.CategoryTitle.object(at: ((myindexpath as NSIndexPath?)?.row)!) as? String
        upcoming.titlestring = titleString
        self.MainPageTableView.deselectRow(at: myindexpath!, animated: true)

    }else  {
        let upcoming: PopOverViewController = segue.destination as! PopOverViewController
        //do rest of your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you help me with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619860/getting-the-values-of-data-stored-in-firebase/39620712#39620712